# Laravel webdav and filesystem can't access drive

Tags: php, laravel, filesystems

So I've mounted in windows my drive `Z:\site` to `network_share` in the root map of my Laravel project.

Mout code:

`mklink /D F:\Development\RPR\site\network_share Z:\site`

In `filesystems.php`, I've added the config like so:

```
'dev' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('../network_share'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/share',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

But when I try to access the directory using `dd(Storage::disk('dev')->path('/'));`, I get `The root path Z:\site is not readable.`...

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here, I just want to be able to access y webdav storage, so I have all the files and uploads on that share and not on the main server.

I have the `pbmedia/laravel-webdav` package installed and I can, using my config add files and read files, that's no issue, but when I read files, I get the contents of it... If I, for example, want to get an image and display it, just like I can do with `asset('path/to/img.png')`, that would help me alot!

the thing is, the webdav doesn't support the `url()`-method... So I can't access the "link" of that...

Any help on this?

Comment: Did you try 'root' => base_path('network_share'); instead storage_path... ?

Comment: Yes, it gives the same readable error. But I just can read the share...